# How to merge objects by value and change property type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects

```
[ { "value": "1", "hobbies": 'netflix'},{ "value": "1", "hobbies": 'food'} ]
```

I want to:

1. Merge objects by `value` attribute
2. Change hobbies property to an array
3. Merge property values

The expected output

```
[ { "value": "1", "hobbies": ['netflix','food']}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need some guidance, i really dont know where to start, any idea? @Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a forEach loop to iterate through the array.

```js
var arr = [ { "value": "1", "hobbies": 'netflix'},{ "value": "1", "hobbies": 'food'} ];

var k = {};
var out = [];
arr.forEach(elm => {
  if(typeof(k[elm.value]) == "undefined")
    k[elm.value] = {value:elm.value, hobbies:[]};
  k[elm.value].hobbies.push(elm.hobbies);
});

Object.keys(k).forEach(key => out.push(k[key]));

console.log(out);
```

Comment: You could use the new nullish coalescing operator instead of using an if statement to determine whether it's undefined: `k[elm.value] = k[elm.value] ?? {value:elm.value, hobbies:[]};`

Comment: As dominik said, i need to learn, how do you came with this solution?

Comment: I'm iterating through the array with a foreach, making each `value` a key in an Object (k) and pushing the hobbies to existing keys in the k object when one exists. Then I just map the k object back to an array at the end to match the output type you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) comes in handy here as it helps you iterate over the array and keep an `accumulator` to store the data in each iteration.

I set the `acc` to be a JSON object (key-value pairs) where the `key` is the value attribute and the `value` is the resulting item with this value.

Along the way, if there is no item with the given key in the `acc`, we add the object as it is while setting `hobbies` as an array instead of a string.

Otherwise, if it does contain such an object, we add it's value to the existing`hobbies` list.

Finally, we take the `values` of the resulting object which gives the list of grouped objects.:

```js
const arr = [ 
  { "value": "1", "hobbies": 'netflix'},
  { "value": "2", "hobbies": 'reading'},
  { "value": "1", "hobbies": 'food'},
];

const res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
    const { value, hobbies } = item;
    acc[value] = acc[value] 
      ? { ...acc[value], hobbies: [...acc[value].hobbies, item.hobbies] } 
      : { ...item, hobbies: [hobbies] };
    console.log(acc);
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: As dominik said, i need to learn, how do you came with this solution?

Comment: thank you, in the future ill need to add more propertys, can i do that with this code?

Comment: @AlexHunter you are welcome. You can use the spread operator as above. This way, all the attributes get added, and the ``hobbies`` gets updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the result for each value. On each iteration, if the current value does not exist as a key in the accumulator object, we create it and initialize the `hobbies` property as an empty array. Then, we add the current hobby to the object at that value. After the `reduce` operation, we use `Object.values` to get an array of all the resulting values.

```js
const arr = [ { "value": "1", "hobbies": 'netflix'},{ "value": "1", "hobbies": 'food'} ];
const res = Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc,{value, hobbies})=>
       ((acc[value] = acc[value] || {value, hobbies: []}).hobbies.push(hobbies), acc),
  {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: As dominik said, i need to learn, how do you came with this solution?